# Windows Store Apps: Difference between WinJS.Promise.join and queueEvent

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-store-apps

My assumption is that the WinJS.Application.queue event applies to queuing Application events in a global context (e.g. checkpoint, unload, activated, loaded...) but has nothing to do with asynchronous calls.  The WinJS.Promise.join can be used within the event handlers setPromise() to ensure that all asynchronous calls are completed before continuing.  Any context or clarification is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're two completely different things.

WinJS.Application.queueEvent is used to raise an event to handlers that are registered with the WinJS.Application.addEventHandler function. Multiple events may be raised over time, and the handlers may be called more than once.

WinJS.Promise.join is used to create a new promise object that completes when all the promises you hand it complete. You need to have promises to begin with, and once the promise completes (success or failure) it stays completed. Your handlers will only ever run once.

They're both for async processing, but they're for different styles of async. Promises are used for something that will go off and do something, and return at some point later, but they'll only run once. Events can happen multiple times over the lifetime of your app.